# Magento2 Varnish issues with customer session and site header

Tags: magento2, php, varnish

Magento version: C.E 2.3.5
Varnish: varnishd (varnish-4.1.1 revision 66bb824)

I am facing a very strange issue. In the admin panel,
Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System -> Cache -> Varnish (recommended)

Now, varnish is enabled on my application.

1. I log into a customer account
2. Access some category pages, homepage, product pages. In my header, I see "Welcome ".
3. I logout from the application
4. Now when the system automatically redirects to hompage (after 5 seconds of logout), in the header, I still see the dropdown with options "My acount", "wish list", logout.
5. If I access the already opened pages like, category pages, product pages, the same issue appears.

**Expected result:**
In the header, the labels, "Sign In  or Create Account" should appear after logout.

**Actual Result:**
The system serves the cached version of the page, with a dropdown to logout for an already logged out user.

I am using a docker setup:
Below is the vcl configuration file:

```
# VCL version 5.0 is not supported so it should be 4.0 even though actually used Varnish version is 6
vcl 4.0;

import std;
# The minimal Varnish version is 6.0
# For SSL offloading, pass the following header in your proxy server or load balancer: 'X-Forwarded-Proto: https'

backend default {
    .host = <docker service name>;
    .port = "80";
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    .probe = {
        .url = "/pub/health_check.php";
        .timeout = 2s;
        .interval = 5s;
        .window = 10;
        .threshold = 5;
   }
}

acl purge {
    <docker service name>;
}

sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.method == "PURGE") {
        if (client.ip !~ purge) {
            return (synth(405, "Method not allowed"));
        }
        # To use the X-Pool header for purging varnish during automated deployments, make sure the X-Pool header
        # has been added to the response in your backend server config. This is used, for example, by the
        # capistrano-magento2 gem for purging old content from varnish during it's deploy routine.
        if (!req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern && !req.http.X-Pool) {
            return (synth(400, "X-Magento-Tags-Pattern or X-Pool header required"));
        }
        if (req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Magento-Tags ~ " + req.http.X-Magento-Tags-Pattern);
        }
        if (req.http.X-Pool) {
          ban("obj.http.X-Pool ~ " + req.http.X-Pool);
        }
        return (synth(200, "Purged"));
    }

    if (req.method != "GET" &&
        req.method != "HEAD" &&
        req.method != "PUT" &&
        req.method != "POST" &&
        req.method != "TRACE" &&
        req.method != "OPTIONS" &&
        req.method != "DELETE") {
          /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
          return (pipe);
    }

    # We only deal with GET and HEAD by default
    if (req.method != "GET" && req.method != "HEAD") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Bypass shopping cart, checkout and search requests
    if (req.url ~ "/checkout" || req.url ~ "/catalogsearch") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Bypass health check requests
    if (req.url ~ "/pub/health_check.php") {
        return (pass);
    }

    # Set initial grace period usage status
    set req.http.grace = "none";

    # normalize url in case of leading HTTP scheme and domain
    set req.url = regsub(req.url, "^http[s]?://", "");

    # collect all cookies
    std.collect(req.http.Cookie);

    # Compression filter. See https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/FAQ/Compression
    if (req.http.Accept-Encoding) {
        if (req.url ~ "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|gz|tgz|bz2|tbz|mp3|ogg|swf|flv)$") {
            # No point in compressing these
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "gzip") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "gzip";
        } elsif (req.http.Accept-Encoding ~ "deflate" && req.http.user-agent !~ "MSIE") {
            set req.http.Accept-Encoding = "deflate";
        } else {
            # unknown algorithm
            unset req.http.Accept-Encoding;
        }
    }

    # Remove all marketing get parameters to minimize the cache objects
    if (req.url ~ "(\?|&)(gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl|zanpid|origin|fbclid|mc_[a-z]+|utm_[a-z]+|_bta_[a-z]+)=") {
        set req.url = regsuball(req.url, "(gclid|cx|ie|cof|siteurl|zanpid|origin|fbclid|mc_[a-z]+|utm_[a-z]+|_bta_[a-z]+)=[-_A-z0-9+()%.]+&?", "");
        set req.url = regsub(req.url, "[?|&]+$", "");
    }

    # Static files caching
    if (req.url ~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
        # Static files should not be cached by default
        return (pass);

        # But if you use a few locales and don't use CDN you can enable caching static files by commenting previous line (#return (pass);) and uncommenting next 3 lines
        #unset req.http.Https;
        #unset req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto;
        #unset req.http.Cookie;
    }

    return (hash);
}

sub vcl_hash {
    if (req.http.cookie ~ "X-Magento-Vary=") {
        hash_data(regsub(req.http.cookie, "^.*?X-Magento-Vary=([^;]+);*.*$", "\1"));
    }

    # For multi site configurations to not cache each other's content
    if (req.http.host) {
        hash_data(req.http.host);
    } else {
        hash_data(server.ip);
    }

    # To make sure http users don't see ssl warning
    if (req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto) {
        hash_data(req.http.X-Forwarded-Proto);
    }
    

    if (req.url ~ "/graphql") {
        call process_graphql_headers;
    }
}

sub process_graphql_headers {
    if (req.http.Store) {
        hash_data(req.http.Store);
    }
    if (req.http.Content-Currency) {
        hash_data(req.http.Content-Currency);
    }
}

sub vcl_backend_response {

    set beresp.grace = 3d;

    if (beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_esi = true;
    }

    if (bereq.url ~ "\.js$" || beresp.http.content-type ~ "text") {
        set beresp.do_gzip = true;
    }

    if (beresp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        set beresp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Control = beresp.http.Cache-Control;
    }

    # cache only successfully responses and 404s
    if (beresp.status != 200 && beresp.status != 404) {
        set beresp.ttl = 0s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        return (deliver);
    } elsif (beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "private") {
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
        set beresp.ttl = 86400s;
        return (deliver);
    }

    # validate if we need to cache it and prevent from setting cookie
    if (beresp.ttl > 0s && (bereq.method == "GET" || bereq.method == "HEAD")) {
        unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    }

   # If page is not cacheable then bypass varnish for 2 minutes as Hit-For-Pass
   if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
       beresp.http.Surrogate-control ~ "no-store" ||
       (!beresp.http.Surrogate-Control &&
       beresp.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache|no-store") ||
       beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
        # Mark as Hit-For-Pass for the next 2 minutes
        set beresp.ttl = 120s;
        set beresp.uncacheable = true;
    }

    return (deliver);
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (resp.http.X-Magento-Debug) {
        if (resp.http.x-varnish ~ " ") {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "HIT";
            set resp.http.Grace = req.http.grace;
        } else {
            set resp.http.X-Magento-Cache-Debug = "MISS";
        }
    } else {
        unset resp.http.Age;
    }

    # Not letting browser to cache non-static files.
    if (resp.http.Cache-Control !~ "private" && req.url !~ "^/(pub/)?(media|static)/") {
        set resp.http.Pragma = "no-cache";
        set resp.http.Expires = "-1";
        set resp.http.Cache-Control = "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0";
    }

    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Debug;
    unset resp.http.X-Magento-Tags;
    unset resp.http.X-Powered-By;
    unset resp.http.Server;
    unset resp.http.X-Varnish;
    unset resp.http.Via;
    unset resp.http.Link;
}

sub vcl_hit {
    if (obj.ttl >= 0s) {
        # Hit within TTL period
        return (deliver);
    }
    if (std.healthy(req.backend_hint)) {
        if (obj.ttl + 300s > 0s) {
            # Hit after TTL expiration, but within grace period
            set req.http.grace = "normal (healthy server)";
            return (deliver);
        } else {
            # Hit after TTL and grace expiration
            return (restart);
        }
    } else {
        # server is not healthy, retrieve from cache
        set req.http.grace = "unlimited (unhealthy server)";
        return (deliver);
    }
}
```

The headers after running below command on home page

```
**curl -I <domain url>**

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 18 Jun 2020 14:42:27 GMT
Server: ====server name======
X-Powered-By: ===php version====
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=471bd6665575857ac82; expires=Thu, 18-Jun-2020 17:42:27 GMT; Max-Age=10800; path=/; domain=<domain name>; HttpOnly
Expires: Fri, 19 Jun 2020 14:42:28 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=86400, public, s-maxage=86400
Pragma: cache
X-Magento-Tags: store,cms_b,cat_c,cat_c_4,cat_c_5,cat_c_6,cms_p_2,cms_b_header_menu,cms_b_page_top_usp_right,cms_b_home_content4,cat_c_p_2,cat_p_29,cat_p,cat_p_28,cat_p_30,cat_p_31,cat_p_26,cat_p_27,amasty_label_4,cms_b_footer_top_section4,cms_b_footer_bottom_above,cms_b_footer_bottom_links
Content-Length: 63720
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

How can I check the headers during login and logout?

Did anyone faced any similar issues?

Comment: Can you please share your VCL file for reference?  I'd also like to see an HTTP request and an HTTP response for the homepage. I only care about the headers, both for request and response. I'm also curious to see a response headers for when you're logged in, and the headers for when you're logged out.

Comment: @ThijsFeryn  I just added your asked information in the description. How can I check the headers during login and logout?

Comment: @anujeet Did you found any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

### Request & response headers using Chrome developer tools

After you logout, please log the headers from the next request. Don't do this using *curl*, because *curl* is stateless, by default it doesn't keep track of cookies unless you explicitly associate a cookie store.

You could use Chrome developer tools to get request & response headers for this request.

### Enable `x-magento-debug`

In `vcl_deliver` there is code to return debugging information. If you enable `x-magento-debug`, probably from within Magento, we'll see more debug information about caching in the response headers.

### Varnishlog

The `varnishlog` binary will help us figure out the behavior of Varnish when these requests happen.

Please send me the output of the following command:

```
varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl eq '/page'"
```

> Please replace `/page` in this expression with the URL of the actual page you're debugging. Please only run this `varnishlog` command exactly when you can reproduce the error in your browser.

The output will contain all headers, all metadata, and the exact behavior of Varnish.

One piece of information that `varnishlog` cannot display by default, is the composition of the *hash key*. I would advise you to run Varnish with the following *runtime parameter*:

```
-p vsl_mask=+Hash
```

This parameter should be added to the runtime parameters that are registered with your `varnishd` programme. This is either done is *Systemd*, or in *Docker*, or any other please you use to manage your Varnish process.

This will allow us to see the `Hash` log lines in the `varnishlog` output, and will help us understand if there are certain cache variations that are causing this behavior.

### Conclusion

The goal is to reproduce the error from a web browser, and send as much information as possible. Extra debugging is possible in Varnish by enabling the `x-magento-debug` flag in Magento.

`varnishlog` will also provide a great deal of information.

Good luck!